# Custom taxonomies are not loaded before i call taxonomy list

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I was using the function

```
get_taxonomies( '', 'names' );
```

in the middle of the plugin code for some use, but i get only 5 standard taxonomies.

I wonder why my other custom taxonomies are not included?
I understand it may be because of priority issue of the init function.

So, i have added an action for this purpse giving the very low priority(99) so that
it calls only after all custom taxonomies are loaded.
Still it is not giving the desired taxonomy list.

Any ideas?

```
add_action('init', 'mycbgenie_update_terms_and_tags', 99);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try with [wp_loaded](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_loaded) action instead of init